# Mongo::Error::OperationFailure (not authorized on [db] to execute command....(13))

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

On my production server, I keep getting `not authorized` error randomly. The following is my setup:

- MongoDB 3.2.1
- Mongo (ruby driver) 2.2.3
- Mongoid 5.1.1
- bson 4.0.2

I don't have username and password configured in `mongoid.yml`. I only have `uri` configured to connect to remote database server.

I search-fu was weak, and couldn't find anything that could explain/help what's going on.

Any help would be much, much appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: Have you checked file permissions, database users and permission, and users that each process in running as?

Comment: They work fine for a long time, and errors pop up randomly. If there is permission issue, it should be present at ALL TIMES, not just randomly. This is why it's so strange and mind boggling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like upgrading to mongo 3.x fixes the problem, as this jira ticket shows.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/RUBY-1100